# Add an answer to a command in shell script

Tags: shell

I am wondering how to add an answer to a command in a shell script. I know this isn't very clear, as I don't know how to describe it. For example:

```
$> su
$> Password: <automatically_fill_in_the_password_here>
```

How would I automatically fill in the password?

Comment: The bigger question is why do you need to? What are you trying to do? It is a bad idea to automatically fill in passwords. There's almost always a better way.

Comment: @JohnKugelman that was an example, I want to fill in something else.

Comment: `su` is a special case. It reads directly from the terminal device rather than stdin, so you can't pipe to it. You'd need something like `expect`.

Comment: @NoahSandman So what do you actually want to do? It's easy to automate lots of kinds of input; su's password prompt is an exception.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I am unzipping a zip file into a directory where it replaces files, and I want to autofill "A" to overwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect` is what you are looking for.

Allow me to quote [this page](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/), as it does a very good job in explaining `expect`:

> **Expect** is a Unix and Linux automation and testing tool. It works with interactive applications such as `telnet`, `ftp`, `passwd`, `fsck`, `rlogin`, `tip`, `ssh`, and many others. It uses Unix pseudo terminals to wrap up subprocesses transparently, allowing the automation of arbitrary applications that are accessed over a terminal.

Below is, a simple expect script to supply OpenSSH root/admin password for remote ssh server and execute the Unix / Linux / BSD commands. (First, you need to [install expect tool by following these instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/execute-commands-on-multiple-hosts-using-expect-tool-part-iii.html).)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# Expect script to supply root/admin password for remote ssh server 
# and execute command.
# This script needs three argument to(s) connect to remote server:
# password = Password of remote UNIX server, for root user.
# ipaddr = IP Addreess of remote UNIX server, no hostname
# scriptname = Path to remote script which will execute on remote server
# For example:
#  ./sshlogin.exp password 192.168.1.11 who 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2004 nixCraft project <http://cyberciti.biz/fb/>
# This script is licensed under GNU GPL version 2.0 or above
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This script is part of nixCraft shell script collection (NSSC)
# Visit http://bash.cyberciti.biz/ for more information.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# set Variables
set password [lrange $argv 0 0] 
set ipaddr [lrange $argv 1 1]   
set scriptname [lrange $argv 2 2] 
set arg1 [lrange $argv 3 3] 
set timeout -1   
# now connect to remote UNIX box (ipaddr) with given script to execute
spawn ssh root@$ipaddr $scriptname $arg1
match_max 100000
# Look for passwod prompt
expect "*?assword:*"
# Send password aka $password 
send -- "$password\r"
# send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
send -- "\r"
expect eof
```

In cas one didn't read the script's comments (you really should), here's how to use it:

```
./sshlogin.exp password 192.168.1.11 who
```

Comment: Thanks! The only downside to this is that it doesn't natively work on Mac, (I don't think), but I'm pretty sure Macports has a port. If I were to distribute a project where I used this, I would need to have this installed on the computer too, right? Thanks,